# Which ODBC-JDBC bridge maps its own calls to JDBC driver?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, odbc

We have some legacy applications that use an ODBC driver for accessing their databases.

I'm looking for an ODBC driver that would be able to map its own calls to a JDBC driver (ODBC-JDBC bridge).

Eventually, I'm interested with some documentation and/or pointers for writing this kind of bridge.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So far I have found only a few paid solutions :

1. [Easysoft](http://www.easysoft.com/) with their [ODBC-JDBC Gateway](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc_jdbc_gateway/index.html)

   - *Install the ODBC driver as any other ODBC driver and then setup it to forward
     its calls to a JDBC driver of your choice*
2. [OpenLink](http://uda.openlinksw.com/) with their [Single](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-jdbc-st/)/[Multi](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-jdbc-mt/) Tier ODBC to JDBC Bridge

   - *Like the one from EasySoft*
3. [Simba](http://www.simba.com) with their [SimbaEngine ODBC SDK](http://www.simba.com/odbc-sdk.htm)

   - *This SDK permits you to [build an ODBC driver with Java](http://www.simba.com/docs/Building-an-ODBC-Driver-with-Java.pdf)*
4. [Progress DataDirect](https://www.progress.com/datadirect-connectors) with their [Sequelink ODBC-JDBC Bridge](https://www.progress.com/odbc/sequelink)

   - *A [guide](https://www.progress.com/docs/default-source/default-document-library/DataDirect/Documents/Support/Getting-Started/sequelink6_odbc.pdf) is available for getting started.*

P.S.:
  You can see the bridges in **1.** and **2.** in action [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13167_01/aldsp/docs20/appdev/jdbcclt.html#1072126).

Answer (score 4):

There is a project on sourceforge that looks suitable, http://odbcjdbc.sourceforge.net/

There is also a JDBC-ODBC bridge available from Oracle but I think that is the reverse of what you want. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/bridge.html

Comment: http://odbcjdbc.sourceforge.net/ seems to be a dead project. Some of the links they provide are broken.