# Connecting to DB2 from Excel for jdbc driver

Tags: excel, db2

We were using Squirrel SQL client to connect to DB2 database.We have imported some jar files like db2java,db2jcc,db2jcc_license_cu,db2jcc4 for connection through Squirrel.

Now the requirement is to connect to DB2 through Excel.
Can anyone give the code snippet for connecting to DB2.

Do we have to install anything else for doing this

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In order to use a database connection from Excel, you need to use ODBC. The ODBC connection for DB2 is provided with the IBM Data Server Client - Driver for ODBC and CLI. You just need to install the client, and 'catalog' the databases (configure the remote instance, and its databases).

- Guide to use data server client - https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21418043

  - Data server client downloads - https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=4020&uid=swg27016878
- Microsoft note - https://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/connect-to-an-ibm-db2-database-HA104019817.aspx
- Catalog node (instance) command - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001944.html
- Catalog database command - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001936.html

In order to check your odbc sources, execute the odbcad32.exe. You do not need JDBC drivers to connect Excel with DB2, however you could eventually use a ODBC-JDBC bridge: [ODBC-JDBC bridge that maps its own calls to JDBC driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352956/odbc-jdbc-bridge-that-maps-its-own-calls-to-jdbc-driver)

And If you are using SQuirreL, you need db2jcc4.jar OR db2jcc.jar, not both of them. One is for JDBC4 and the other for JDBC3 or before.